# Where should DB connection pool be initialized in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to use psycopg2 (directly, without SQLAlchemy). Also, I would prefer using a connection pool to avoid initializing database connections on every request, as opposed to what (I think?) [official docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#storing-data) recommend.

However, Flask app context has approximately the same lifetime as request context, which is the lifetime of the request, so defining the pool there would not make sense. The only cross-request place I found is in a global variable on module level, which seems to work, but I'm worried if this is safe?

In other words, where is the correct place to initialize a DB connection pool in a Flask application so that it is used across requests?